# How can ı ajax request with json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a API . I want to get data and ı want to that data write to input. I used AJAX but nothing happened when click submit button

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $('#ajaxBtn').click(function(){
        $.ajax("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
        {
            dataType: 'json', // type of response data
            timeout: 500,     // timeout milliseconds
            success: function (data,status,xhr) {   // success callback function
                $('p').append(data.firstName + ' ' + data.middleName + ' ' + data.lastName);
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) { // error callback 
                $('p').append('Error: ' + errorMessage);
            }
        });
     });

    });




    <input type="button" id="ajaxBtn" value="Send Ajax request" />
<p>
</p>
```

Comment: Did you check the console.log(data) output? Is your javascript part in an external file or put like this in the html?

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happened? Please mention the output or error received in the question details. Also your HTML tags are formatted incorrectly.

Comment: @nightslit ı checked everything. I want to external file but ı couldnt

Answer (score 1):

1) Include the jquery library if not
2) Add script tag

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" ></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $('#ajaxBtn').click(function(){
            $.ajax("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
                {
                    dataType: 'json', // type of response data
                    // timeout: 500,     // timeout milliseconds
                    success: function (data,status,xhr) {   // success callback function
                        console.log(data);
                        $('p').append('Todo ID: ' + data.id + ' | Title:' + data.title + ' | UserId: ' + data.userId);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) { // error callback
                        $('p').append('Error: ' + errorMessage);
                    }
                });
        });

    });
</script>


<input type="button" id="ajaxBtn" value="Send Ajax request" />
<p>
</p>
```

Comment: I couldn't find out what the problem was but that worked

Comment: ı did but ı havent 15 reputation